# не работает код vkbottle

Tags: python, асинхронность, vkbottle

Впервые хотел написать бота в вк, но не работает код...

---

```
from vkbottle.bot import Bot, Message
from config import token

bot = Bot(token=token)

@bot.on.message(text='start')
async def echo(message: Message):
    await message.answer(message.text)

bot.run_forever()
```

---

Ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120)

Comment: Вы умеете отличать ошибки от обычных логов? На картинке нет никаких ошибок - просто логи уровня INFO и DEBUG. Вот эта простыня, которую вы приложили - очевидно просто копия логов, но даже если бы там была ошибка, то никакого желания ломать глаза, высматривая её там у меня не возникает.

Comment: Ещё. Не работает код - не объяснение, вам нужно описать ожидаемое поведение программы и что происходит на деле.

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Установите библиотеку `loguru`. Тогда будет удобнее и понятнее видно, что **это не ошибки** а информационные сообщения (логи) о том, что программа работает нормально.

Answer (score 0):

Как уже ответили в комментариях: **это не ошибки**. Этот код работает. То, что вы видите, это [логи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB_%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0), которые сообщают, что программа работает нормально, без ошибок (`INFO` и `DEBUG`). Чуть подробнее про это есть в [документации vkbottle](https://vkbottle.readthedocs.io/ru/latest/modules/).